# Trying to send a video-file to peerconnection media track instead of video stream from camera device

Tags: video-streaming, webrtc

I have finished a webrtc c++ program in my pc(ubuntu18.04). I can run the program successfully, and the remote peer can get video stream from my camera device.

Now I need to start a pressure test. However, the camera device can be used by only one program at one time. So I wonder if I can send a video-file to the media track instead of use my camera device.

I have no idea how to do so. I'm now reading the video-engine code, and I don't know if I'm reading the target part.

I would be really grateful if you have any suggestion!!

Long

Answer (score 0):

It’s easy to do with browser Chrome
https://webrtc.org/testing/

There are 2 useful flags for this:

1) --use-fake-device-for-media-stream feeds a test pattern to getUserMedia() instead of live camera input.

2) --use-file-for-fake-video-capture=path/to/file.y4m feeds a Y4M test file to getUserMedia() instead of live camera input.

Regading custom desktop app I suggest to look into “custom video capture” - this is when you fully control input buffers and can actually provide any information (images, video file) into it